# Make a sliding like a link

Tags: javascript, html, css

How to make section sliding like on http://basharova.ru/?

Main question is how to make and follow scrolling if all elements have absolute position and top: 0?

I tried to make body.style.height = height of all sections, but how to do returning to previous section?

With blackout opacity i had idea to get opacity value from height of visible part of previous section.

Answer (score 0):

It's called "Parallax" and there are libraries to get this done. This is a nice overview: https://cssanimation.rocks/parallax/